# this parent children not working

Tags: jquery

### Why doesn't this work?

HTML

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="viewport">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="img/boat1.png" />
        <img src="img/boat2.png" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn_prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn_next">next</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.viewport {position: relative; height: 220px; width: 280px; overflow: hidden; }
.wrapper  {position: absolute; height: 220px; width: 9999px;}
```

jQuery - this bit works fine

```
$(".wrapper").stop().animate({left: '-312px'}, 500);
```

jQuery - but if i add parent.children it dies

```
$(".btn_next").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).parent().children(".wrapper").stop().animate({left: '-312px'}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `.wrapper` is nested one level deeper, so it isn't a child.

Use `.find()` instead.

```
$(this).parent().find(".wrapper")
```

---

Indenting your HTML properly makes it much clearer...

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="img/boat1.png" />
            <img src="img/boat2.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn_prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn_next">next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, worked perfectly, one thing that is weird though is that adding in children(".viewport") before .children(".wrapper") didn't work.

Comment: @Brae: You mean `$(this).parent().children(".viewport").children(".wrapper")` didn't work? That's strange. It should work that way.

Comment: I don't know how to reply to names with spaces xD, but yeah thats why i was stuck.